# I made a change in Storyboard, now every run starts by SIGBART;ing

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, sigabrt

I'm trying to get into iOS programming. I have the latest XCode, 4.2 Build 4D177b. I started with a single view application with ARC. I placed a UITextField on it and used dragging to get the property in the code.

Then I decided to change the UITextField to a UIButton. Ever since that every run has gone straight to SIGABRT on the standard line in main:

```
  return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

I have deleted that UIButton after disconnecting the IBOutlet, but I still get SIGABRT as the very first thing. With breakpoints on every line, it never stops at any of them. I have done Clean, I have even rebooted, but all I get is SIGABRT, in an apparently indefinite loop.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I confirm this behaviour on my side with XCode 4.2. When the IOS simulator has been launched a couple of times and the project has been "bounced" many times as well. I restart the Mac and it works well again, hem...

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems.

If you remove a variable in code that's linked to a storyboard field, be sure to remove it's linkage in the storyboard.

In my case, I changed the name of a field in storyboard. Then I removed the old variable in code. Then I created the new variable in code by CTRL dragging the storyboard field to the .h file. SIGABRT resulted. Then I right clicked the new field in storyboard. Voila ... the old named field was STILL linked even though that field no longer existed in code or in the storyboard. I eliminated that old linkage and no more SIGABRT.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me lots of time. I just wanted to add to what you said about eliminating the linkage. Not sure how you did it, but I opened Main.storyboard when XCode was closed and removed the offending field.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your "File's owner" in Interface Builder goes not have your component still linked and that you change your code so the IBOutlet is of the same class as your component.

If you change the component type from UITextField to UIButton, you also have to change the class type for the outlet in your class.h file.

Comment: Thanks, Øystein. There is nothing called File's Owner in the IB panel, There is a section, to the left of the design area, called View Controller Scene. It has 2 top level objects, First Responder and View Controller. The View Controller has a sub-element called View. If I bring up the floating black listing of links for View Controller, it has a single link showing, which is from its properly view to the View.

Comment: I did remember to edit the class of the variables. The current state is that all that stuff has been removed. There are no extra properties or added controls. I'm guessing there is something in XML of MainStoryboard.storyboard that is confusing it.

Answer (score 0):

I left the app alone for a few days to do other tasks and just now came back to it and it worked well stopped at all the break points, and came up with the blank window, which was all that was left.

So, a bit of a mystery, but I see 4.3 is out. Maybe it will be more stable for me.

Comment: I have the same issue and hat it many times before. But this time I cannot find a workaround by removing UI elements step by step. But for the first time I took this menu path and it sounds weird ... Storyboard -> Open As -> Propertylist (inteface builder opens the storyboard and I cannot figure out any issues).
    -> data couldn't be read because it has been corrupted

Comment: Storyboard files cannot be opened via Open As -> Propertylist ... even a new project showd error message "data could not be read because it has been corrupted".